# Disable multiple users login in Moqui

Tags: moqui

I want to prevent multiple logins with same credentials (from different browsers on the same machine or from different machines) in Moqui.

I read about `HttpSessionBindingListener`, unfortunately it only works when I login the second time on the same browser (in a different tab).
But if I change browser (on the same machine) it doesn't work anymore. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

`same credentials` - it means same user. You don't concern about singe or multiple login since it is the same user. If web-app has error, it is the user's error.